# Analyzing a trajectory

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I have the discrete dynamical system $f(x) = 13xe^{-x}$ and want to know its stable period 4 orbit, its fixed points, and period 2 orbit. Of course also check stability of these things as well.

I've been choosing a bunch of different starting points for the period 4 orbits and it seems that for any starting point $x_0 > 0$ then eventually the period 4 orbit stabilizes to some point. However, not all starting points result in the trajectory converging to the same point.

`f[x_] := 13. x E^-x
 bit2 = Nest[f, 1.5, #] & /@ Prepend[1]@Range[4, 400, 4]
 bit6 = Nest[f, 47, #] & /@ Prepend[1]@Range[4, 400, 4]`

results with

```
{4.35104, 0.614346, 0.600992, 0.58616, 0.570842, 0.556566, 0.544936, \
0.536853, 0.532063, 0.529574, 0.528389, 0.527851, 0.527613, 0.527508, \
0.527463, 0.527443, 0.527435, 0.527431, 0.527429, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428, \
0.527428, 0.527428, 0.527428}

-------
    {2.36701*10^-18, 5.20033*10^-15, 1.48527*10^-10, 
 4.24206*10^-6, 0.119941, 4.39942, 4.38187, 4.35943, 4.33111, \
4.29618, 4.25472, 4.20845, 4.16142, 4.11943, 4.08758, 4.06727, \
4.05616, 4.05071, 4.0482, 4.04707, 4.04658, 4.04637, 4.04627, \
4.04623, 4.04621, 4.04621, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, \
4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, \
4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, \
4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, \
4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, \
4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, \
4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, \
4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, \
4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, \
4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462, 4.0462}
```

Those are just two examples of points I tested. 
So what is happening? I haven't found the Stable period-$4$ orbit because the trajectories keep converging to different points for different value of starting point. Any starting point I try results in the trajectory converging to a different point though so i'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've found two different points on the orbit of period 4, since your `Range` command only generates every fourth integer.  I'd try this:

```
f[x_] = 13 x*Exp[-x];
NestList[f, 1.0, 60][[-5 ;;]]

(* Out: {0.919916, 4.76625, 0.527428, 4.0462, 0.919916} *)
```

Note that I've started the iteration at the critical point `1.0`, since an attractive orbit *must* attract a critical point. I'm using `NestList`, rather than `Nest` for a bunch of different arguments. And, I'm not skipping points, so I can *see* the actual orbit, that is:
$$0.919916 \to 4.76625 \to 0.527428 \to 4.0462 \to 0.919916.$$
Things have settled down since the `[[-5;;]]` construct grabs the last five terms in the orbit. I don't think it makes sense to examine just every fourth term in your orbit for then, how can you distinguish an orbit of period 4 from a fixed point or an orbit of period 2?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I'm not clear on what the `[[-5 ;;]]` syntax does. For my `Range` function, I thought that was exactly what I wanted that way I would generate $f^{(4)}, f^{(8)}, f^{(12)}, \cdots$ and so on. So i'm not sure why we would change from that.

Comment: @talnn I edited my answer a bit to address your questions.

Comment: Thanks for updating your Answer. I think I may be a bit confused on definitions. An _orbit_ is a cycle with in a trajectory right? I'm confused on what it means to be stable for this. I thought that period-$4$ trajectories were defined to be points at every fourth interval of the function. i.e, $f^{(4)}(x_0), f^{(8)}(x_0), \cdots$. I know what a starting point of trajectory being Stable means, but for an Orbit? I'm not so sure.

Comment: And [this](http://i.imgur.com/tibNJ7w.png) shows I should have several fixed points for $f^{(4)}$. Just for additional information

Comment: @talnn I hesitate to clarify your questions on the definitions, as they might vary from author to author. In particular, I would say that a trajectory and an orbit are synonymous. Generally, though, an orbit starting at $x_0$ is periodic with period $n$ if $f^n(x_0)=x_0$ but $f^k(x_0)\neq x_0$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$. Note that $x_0$ is then a fixed point of $f^n$, as are all the points in the orbit. The orbit is attractive if $x_0$ is an attractive fixed point of $f^n$. An application of the chain rule shows that all the points in the orbit must also be attractive fixed points of $f^n$.